# Creating building footprints from LAS files

Tags: polygon, fme-form, lidar, classification, las

I wish to create building footprints from the classification in our LAS files.  I have filtered out the building points, using the point cloud filter. But I now trying to join the outermost points of the buildings, which I can't figure out how to achieve this. I understand that this may be a little hit and miss with the LAS classifications but I am happy to accept this. I am a inexperienced FME user.

[image: The image shows the extents of the classification of buildings]

Comment: I can't give you the proper (series of) FME transformer, but this may point you in the right direction. What you want to achieve is a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), grouped by points within a certain distance (to have separate polygons for each building). The grouping part shouldn't be too complicated, I suppose, it's just about finding the proper distance between points to filter out all that belong to a single building.

Comment: Polygon from Point Cloud https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/5083/polygon-from-point-cloud.html

Answer (score 3):

Have a read of the following link [Concave Hull and the Alpha Value](https://blog.safe.com/2012/05/fmeevangelist105/), which was what I was trying to achieve by joining the Classified LIDAR building data and creating polygons around clusters of these points.  Secondly as suggested look at this previously posted question [Polygon from Point Cloud](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/5083/polygon-from-point-cloud.html).  Or review the attached image with my workflow, very important to read the metadata that comes with the LIDAR data.  Some of the issues I found was the density of points and I had issues with the classification of data with incorrect values placed on points, causing my buildings to come out incorrect/slither polygons through buildings (but it did what i was trying to achieve).[image: Building footprints workflow].

Answer (score 1):

Best Way for free Building Footprint data. Use it once and you will get best output:

- Go to Arc tool box add LAStools.tbx.
- Drop down tool, you will see multiple of tools.
- First click **Las Ground provide Las file as input** and run - It will give you output.
- Now Run **Las Height**, provide **Las ground output as input for Las height**.
- Now run **Las Classify**, Provide **Las Height output as input for Las Classify**.
- Now run **Las Boundary**, Provide **Las classify output as input for Las Boundary** provide **concavity - 8** best as per my study, **Use option - Select Building**.

Output will be your Building Footprint.

**Note**: Please don't change any options given in default by tool. I didn't change it and found the best output.